# Add easing to variable calculation based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scrolltop, easing

I have some text elements that should move in their x-axis based on the scroll position.
Please see this pen for reference:

https://codepen.io/magglomag/pen/GRZwRNB

HTML

```
<h1 class="moving-text-wrapper">
  <div class="moving-text moving-text-1" data-scroll-speed="-4">Lorem</div>
  <div class="moving-text moving-text-2" data-scroll-speed="2">ipsum</div>
  <div class="moving-text moving-text-3" data-scroll-speed="9">sonsetetur</div>
  <div class="moving-text moving-text-4" data-scroll-speed="-6">sit</div>
  <div class="moving-text moving-text-5" data-scroll-speed="3">amet</div>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
html {
  height: 300vh;
}

.moving-text-wrapper {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.moveIt = function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];
  
  $(this).each(function(){
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var elemOffsetTop = $( '.moving-text-wrapper' ).offset().top;
    var translateX = elemOffsetTop - scrollTop - $( window ).height()/2;

    instances.forEach(function(inst){
      inst.update(translateX);
    });
  }, {passive: true});
}

var moveItItem = function(el){
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(translateX){
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateX(' + -(translateX / this.speed) + 'px)');
};

$(function(){
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

What I’d like to add is a little easing to the variable `translateX`, so when the scrolling stops the text will move a little bit longer and does not stop directly like in the current pen.

Any hints how to solve that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was quite easy to solve with CSS transitions:

I just added a transition to the elements like this:

```
.moving-text {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

See updated Codepen for reference:
https://codepen.io/magglomag/pen/YzqRPoX